# std::regex infinite loop with gcc 5.4

Tags: regex, c++11, gcc

The `std::regex_match()` doesn't finish (GCC 5.4.0 20160609, x86_64, Ubuntu 16.04).

But it works in some of online compilers: http://cpp.sh/ is ok, for exemple.

The code tries to match an INI-style section header with a possible "#"-comment.

```
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::regex headerPattern("([[:blank:]]*\\[[[:blank:]]*((?:[[:blank:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:blank:]]*?)+)[[:blank:]]*\\][[:blank:]]*(?:#(?:[^[:space:]]*[[:blank:]]*)*)?)");
    std::smatch headerMatch;
    std::string l("[Hdr 100] # ------------ 22 22 4444 88888888 333");
    return std::regex_match(l, headerMatch, headerPattern) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Build:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
```

Is there really a problem with the code?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern causes catastrophic backtracking. It happens because you have a repeated capturing group `((?:[[:blank:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:blank:]]*?)+)` (for simplicity, let me write it using PCRE syntax as `((?:\h*\S+\h*?)+)`) and it matches 0+ horizontal whitespace, then 1 or more non-whitespace chars, followed with 0+ horizontal whitespace, and all this is quantified with `+`. This is a classical `(a+)+` case inside a pattern that makes the catastrophic backtracking inevitable.

You need to unroll this and the other group the following way:

```
std::regex headerPattern("([[:blank:]]*\\[[[:blank:]]*([^[:space:]]+(?:[[:blank:]]+[^[:space:]]+)*)[[:blank:]]*\\][[:blank:]]*(?:#[^[:space:]]*(?:[[:blank:]]+[^[:space:]]+)*)?)");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Re4OF/1). And here is a [PCRE-converted variant](https://regex101.com/r/0orCAf/1) to understand the difference: the group I mentioned above is now `\S+(?:\h+\S+)*`: 1+ non-whitespace chars, followed with 0+ sequences of 1+ horizontal whitespace chars followed with 1+ non-whitespace chars. The last capturing group  is changed to `\S*(?:\h+\S+)*`: 0+ non-whitespace chars followed with 0+ sequences of 1+ horizontal whitespace chars followed with 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Just replace `\h` with `[[:blank:]]` (or `[^\\S\r\n]`) and `\S` with `[^[:space:]]` (or keep it, `std::regex` supports it) to revert that PCRE pattern to the one you used.